# Migrating categories from Entry to Asset

Tags: migration

Is it possible to migrate content like categories from an entry to an asset easily?

Each entry has an image asset and I'd like to move all the categories on the entry to the asset.

Would this require a SQL operation or is there any easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably do this in two steps:

1. Create a twig file formatted as a CSV that outputs the category and asset id's, i.e.

```
AssetId, Category<br>
{% for entry in entries %}
{{ entry.asset.one().id }}, {% for category in categories %}{{ category.id }}{% if not loop.last %}-|-{% endif %}{% endfor %}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

2. Use [feed me](https://plugins.craftcms.com/feed-me) to re-import the categories onto the assets using the CSV.

Comment: Clever! Will try this, thank you!